# How to test whether the relationship between an IV and a DV varies depending on levels of two other variables

Tags: r, modeling, contrasts, lm

Let's say I have 2 different conditions participants can be assigned to (stored in the variable `condition`). Within each `condition`, participants can be assigned to 1 of 4  `treatments`.

I have an outcome, `Y`, and a moderator variable, `X` and I want to know whether the relationship between `X` and `Y` depends on (and in what ways) the specific cell a participant was assigned to (treatment * condition).

My current thought about how to model this is as the following:

```
lm(Y ~ treatment/X -1,
  data = df %>% filter(condition == "Condition A"))
```

And then run another model where you filter to the other condition

```
lm(Y ~ treatment/X -1,
  data = df %>% filter(condition == "Condition B"))
```

This results in the following table of coefficients:

```
                                           Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)  CI Lower  CI Upper  DF
treatment1                                3.4278052   3.337427  1.027080 0.30515602 -3.138188  9.993798 321
treatment2                               14.3758462   3.736847  3.847052 0.00014421  7.024042 21.727651 321
treatment3                                6.5085711   4.007973  1.623906 0.10537746 -1.376643 14.393785 321
treatment4                                2.3855668   3.034684  0.786101 0.43238845 -3.584815  8.355948 321
treatment1:X                             -0.0133485   0.054582 -0.244557 0.80695532 -0.120732  0.094035 321
treatment2:X                             -0.0478219   0.061340 -0.779624 0.43618685 -0.168501  0.072857 321
treatment3:X                              0.0876736   0.078806  1.112525 0.26674492 -0.067368  0.242715 321
treatment4:X                             -0.0036413   0.058255 -0.062506 0.95019843 -0.118250  0.110968 321
```

I assume the coefficients with the interactions measure the within-treatment effect of the independent variable on the dependent variable. Is this the appropriate way to test this kind of question? Is there a cleaner way to consolidate all the tests into a single model (instead of subsetting)?

Another thought was the following model:

```
lm(Y ~ treatment:condition:X -1,
  data = df)
```

Which only models the three-way interactions between treatment, condition, and X. But I'm not exactly sure that's what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do

```r
lm(Y ~ X * condition * treatment, data = df)
```

and then look at the coefficients for the following interaction terms to see if they're significantly different from zero:

- `X:condition`: the average effect of `X` on `Y` depends on the type of `condition`
- `X:treatment`: the average effect of `X` on `Y` depends on the type of `treatment`
- `X:condition:treatment`: the average effect of `X` on `Y` depends on both the type of `condition` and the type of `treatment`

Note that these interpretations assume the coefficients to be significantly different from zero.

---

*Edit after the discussion in the comments:*

I've simulated some data that might resemble yours:

```r
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(96, 10, 2)
treatment <- c(rep(1,24), rep(2,24), rep(3,24), rep(4,24))
condition <- rep(rep(c('A','B'), each = 12), 4)
y <- x * treatment + if_else(condition == 'A', rnorm(96, 4, 1), 0)

data <- data.frame(
  x = x,
  treatment = factor(treatment),
  condition = factor(condition),
  y = y
)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, shape = treatment, colour = condition)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: Scatterplot of simulated data]

Then I've fitted the linear model I mentioned above:

```r
model <- lm(y ~ x * treatment * condition, data)
```

And then I've plotted the fitted regression lines on top of the data to get an idea of how the different treatments and conditions might impact the effect of `X` on `Y`:

```r
data %>% 
  mutate(fitted_values = fitted(model)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, shape = treatment, colour = condition)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = fitted_values))
```

[image: Scatterplot with regression lines]

Comment: Thanks, Adria! I think the issue with this approach is that, because there are multiple treatments, the coefficient: `X:treatment` is actually interpreted as the average effect of `X` on `Y`, given a specific treatment, _relative to the left-out base case_. That is, with these fully interacted models, one treatment and one condition will be left out, so all the coefficients are just interpreted as relative to the reference case. But I want a more general answer of whether `X` moderates the effect of `treatment` on `Y`, for specific values of `condition`. Should I just rotate the base case?

Comment: @Parseltongue Could you use the fitted model to get a good idea of the effects you're interested in? I'll update my answer to include a simulated example to show what I mean.

Comment: Oh, that's a very nice idea, especially just to visualize if there is something meaningful there. Do you know if there's a more robust way to get the actual slope from all those fitted regression lines, and to test whether they're significantly different from 0?

Comment: @Parseltongue That's what the interaction terms are. For example, if the coefficient for `X:condition` is significantly different from zero (small p-value) then that's evidence that the impact of `X` on `Y` is different depending on the condition i.e. different slopes for the blue and red lines.

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you help me understand a perennial confusion of mine, then? Let's say the coefficient on `conditionA:X` is .0473 and it's not significant (`p=.879`) That coefficient and p-value is _relative_ to the left out condition `conditionB`, correct? What it's saying is that, within condition A, there is a .0473 greater increase in the DV for every 1 unit change in `X` than there is in condition B. Or is it saying, just in the abstract, within condition A, a one unit increase in the `X` is associated with a .0473 increase in the DV?

Comment: My confusion stems from the fact that the slopes in the fitted plot are a combination of the coefficients and standard errors from the regression output. For example, the very top most line is (treatment 4 condition B). That slope will be a combination of 3 coefs: the main effect of treatment 4 + the main effect of condition B + the interaction of those two. The standard error for that joint combination doesn't appear in the regression table.

Comment: What I'd like is to know the slope and standard errors of each of those fitted lines and whether they're significantly different from 0. (And a way to compare specific pairs of slopes)